# Is there a way to set console dimensions and font size using window.h

Tags: c++, windows

At the start of the program I want to set width and height of window, as well as font size. I can do this manually in settings but I would like to do it in code. I wont need to resize window after its dimensions are set.

This doesn't have to be in windows.h, but I'd prefer it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I recommend taking a look at [the win32 console API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). In particular you can use [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) to change the font, and a combination of [`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) and [`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) to change the console size. Make sure to read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo#remarks) section of `SetConsoleWindowInfo` for why the screen buffer size must be updated as well.